# Effect of differentiation on function growth rate

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, asymptotics

For sufficiently "nice" functions, the differentiation operator appears to make slow growing functions grow slower and fast growing functions grow faster, with $e^x$ as a fixed point in the middle.

[image]

My question is, how can we make this statement precise while still retaining as much generality as possible?

---

Clearly, there are all sorts of oscillatory and fractal-like functions for which the statement does not hold, which we must exclude in some manner. This feels similar to the [Gronwall inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality), but I'm having trouble making a precise connection.