# A function and its derivative chasing tails

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, exponential-function

For which $t\ge0$ does there exist a differentiable function $f$ with $f(0)=0$, $f'(x)>f(x)$ for all $x>0$ and with $f'(0)=t$?

This question was inspired by (and is a variation of) the [following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1576874) and its [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1576928).

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)>f(x)$ for all $x>0$.
It could be shown then, as in the answer referred to above, 
that $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$.
The solution goes as follows (with some details added).

Let $g(x)=e^{-x} f(x)$. Because $g'(x)=e^{-x}\Bigl(f'(x)-f(x\Bigr)>0$ we have that $g(x)$ is strictly increasing on the interval $(0,\infty)$. Since $g(0)=0$ we have $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$, hence $f(x)=e^x g(x)>0$ whenever $x\in(0,\infty)$.

On close inspection this argument works even if we add to the assumptions the requirement that $f'(0)<0$. This seems contradictory, since then on one hand $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$, but on the other hand $f(x)<0$ for all $x\in(0,\varepsilon)$, for some small enough $\varepsilon>0$. This contradiction only shows that no such $f$ exist that satisfy all these conditions (including 
$f'(0)<0$). 
Thus the following:

**Question**.  For which $t\ge0$ does there exist an $f$ with $f'(0)=t$, 
and with $f(0)=0$, $f'(x)>f(x)$ for all $x>0$?

Easily $t≥1$ works, e.g. $f(x)=e^{tx}−1$. I wonder if any $t<1$ might also work, in particular if $t=0$ works.

I feel the solution may have something to do with the notion of blow up as understood in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2835), but I don't seem to be able to figure the details. Tried to get a modification of $e^{-\frac1{x^2}}$ but it only works on a bounded interval of positive reals, not on all of $(0,\infty)$. Thank you for your help.

(I included tag integration only because I thought the answer may have also something to do with the average value of $f$ on any interval $[a,b]$, defined as $\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) dx$. In particular the average value of $f'(x)$ on $[0,b]$ is $\frac1b\int_0^b f'(x) dx=f(b)$.)

Comment: If I understand well your question $f(x)=txe^x$ works, for  $t>0$. And $f(x)=x^2e^x$ works for $t=0$.

Comment: Yes, for $t>0$ your example works. I should have spent more time trying to come up with an example, somehow I expected there may be no such examples. What about $t=0$? (let me also read an answer that someone just posted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with a function of the form 
$$f(x) = g(x)e^x,$$ 
for some nonnegative $g(x)$ with positive derivative. Then 
$$f'(x) = g'(x)e^x + f(x) > f(x).$$

Also, I think this is related to the question I asked here:
[Effect of differentiation on function growth rate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131077/effect-of-differentiation-on-function-growth-rate)
about function growth rates.

---

**Edit:**

Also, if you are only interested in the existence of such a function and not a simple formula, one could use the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs. One sets up the following ODE:
$$f'(x) = f(x) + w(x),$$ 
with the boundary condition 
$$f(0)=0.$$ 
Then for any "gap" function $w$ with 
$$w(0)=t,$$ 
the other "boundary condition"
$$f'(0)=0 + w(0) = t$$ 
is also guaranteed to be satisfied as well.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. You also assume $g(0)=0$ (since $0=f(0)=g(0))$ and you may allow $g'(0)=t\ge0$ even if you need $g'(x)>0$ for $x>0$. So $g(x)=e^{-\frac1{x^2}}$ solves the $t=0$ case, and $g(x)=e^{tx}$ solves the $t>0$ case (where another solution was given by @OmranKouba in a comment). Will take a look at the related question that you pointed me to.